# Developing react-native library which is dependent on a native framework

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I am developing a react-native library. This library project internally references another native library project written in swift (for ios). Currently the react-native library contains the following in its podspec file:

```
pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name         = "myReactNativeLibrary"
  s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.summary      = "summary"
  s.dependency "MySwiftFramework"
  s.dependency "React"
```

This way whenever someone includes the react-native library in their app and does a `pod install`, they will also install `MySwiftFramework`

However this makes testing changes in both react-native library and MySwiftFramework a pain.
What would be a best way to test both the library projects locally on a test project?

What I have tried so far:
removed MySwiftFramework from s.dependency in the podspec file and tried manually adding the local MySwiftFramework.xcframework to test react-native app in xcode. Doing so gives an error:
`Module MySwiftFramework` not found.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by "testing changes"?